# Wordpress get the previous/next buttons to work using category inside article

Tags: php, wordpress

So I modified the single-news.php file in order to get a previous/next button to navigate the news but that code uses the post id and for example im at post1 which belongs to category1, what I press "next" it doesnt go the next post in the same category necessarily.

```
    <?php
if ( is_single() ):
    $prev = get_previous_post_link();
    $prev = str_replace( '&laquo;', '<div class="wrapper"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>', $prev );
    $prev = str_replace( '</a>', '</a></div>', $prev );
    $next = get_next_post_link();
    $next = str_replace( '&raquo;', '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></div>', $next );
    $next = str_replace( '<a', '<div class="wrapper"><a', $next );
    ?>
    <div class="shapely-next-prev row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left" >
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $prev ) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $next ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea on how I should modify this code? I've seen that this has been asked many times but I couldnt implement the ideas from these posts.

I have tried that but it doenst show anything:

```
$next = next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' );
```

Also for the news I use the Wp news and Scrolling widgets

Edit:
when I use this I have the same result as now

```
    $next = get_next_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', FALSE);
```

but when I use it like this is doesn't show anything:

```
    $next = get_next_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">           
    <div class="wrapper">          
      <?php
        next_post_link('
        %link <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>',
        '%title',true,'','news-category');
      ?>          
    </div>        
</div>
```

So this is the solution and this was the problem: I had to change the categories permalink, in my occasion 'news-category' and then implement that into the next_post_link, because if I just the taxonomy true without specifying the taxonomy-category it is looking in the wrong place.